# checking if current user is author of the document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a formA where I have a field '_author' which is of type Authors/Computed for display with value (@Subset($Updatedby;1)). I display information from formA on viewA. What I want to achieve is that documents that are created by you are only visible to yourself on viewA. I tried the following formula in viewA 'View Selection':
SELECT (form = "formA" & @UserName =_author). Even though I know that these two variables have the same values when I read it from the document's properties, the condition is not satisfied and I do not see a single document. If I delete everything after "&", the view shows all documents.
All is hosted on a server which handles users.

Comment: You've forgotten that the index of the view is build Server side and won't be recalculated for each user (unless you defined it private on first use. I don't recommand this last setting for many reasons).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A handy workaround is to create a Page with an embedded view. This view is exactly like your view but has an additional first categorized (!) column with your field `_author`.

Put into embedded view's property "Show single category" the formula `@UserName` or `@Name([CN]; @UserName)` depending on how your categorized column `_author` is formatted. Show then always the Page instead of the view.

This way you avoid trouble with "Shared, private on first use" views and users see exactly their own documents only.

Comment: created page, created new view with additional categorized column with "_author". In embedded view's properties I have only two, "embedded selection" and "show single category". In show single category i put @UserName, and when I run the page, I get "Category not found". Where is this "show selected only" property to be found of the embedded view?

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry, you're right, the property is called "Show single category". Try it with `@Name([CN]; @UserName)` there.

Comment: This solution also boost performances for users allowed to see only few docs in view containing lot of docs.

Comment: @Emmanuel: we have a good performance experience with single category embedded views - the view is calculated, it has to show only all documents for one category. It's definitely better to go with this than private views.

Comment: @Knut we both agree... It's what I said (maybe should have explain a bit more like you did)

Comment: I was thinking about user seing only 0.01% of 100000 docs that are waiting very long time until they can view 10 docs! (because server side Domino has to walk all the docs to check the READER field) using a single category in such a case is MUST have.

Comment: @Emmanuel oh yes, I see, I am sorry, I misunderstood the word "boost". I looked it up now and yes, we both agree :)

Answer (score 1):

`@UserName` works in a special manner in selection formulas in views. In your case the view should be `Private on First Use`. Read further here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21089773 .

Be aware that this lead to all sort of issues, e.g. when you update the design of the view users must remove the view manually to get the changes deployed.

Comment: It's also worth noting that since a SPOFU view is only reindexed when the user accesses it, and because the user's computer must do the work, large SPOFU views can be slow. Also, if you were to write an agent that runs on the server but relies on a SPOFU view, it can never be sure that the view will be up to date.