# select statement in view selection

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to select only the documents that fulfill the following conditions (I put the statement into "View Selection" of the view's property). What I want to achieve is the following logic:
If user has [roleA]
SELECT(formA & status=1)
if user has [roleB]
SELECT(formA & status = 2)
if user has [roleB]
SELECT(formA & status = 3)

Instead SELECT gets appened to the front and the statement does not work or does not give back the desired results.I have tried the following statement:
SELECT @If(@IsMember("[roleA]"; @UserRoles);
 (form = "formA" & status="1"); 1=1)
this does not provide wanted results. All is hosted on a server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use user specific functions in view select. The selection is done on server by server with server's credentials.

Create three views instead - for each role a separate. Link then user to "their" view depending on @UserRoles in an outline e.g.

Another way is using an embedded view in a Page like suggested in your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710155/2065611). This time first categorized column would be `status` and "Show single category" would have formula

```
@If(@IsMember("[roleA]"; @UserRoles); "1"; @IsMember("[roleB]"; @UserRoles); "2"; "3")
```

Comment: I have a finite number of roles. Can you provide guidance how to link users to their corresponding view as well as keeping in mind that I want users to only see documents that they created? thx!!

Comment: Are you looking for the combination of both = show user only documents they created **and** have the appropriate role?

Comment: If yes, then you have to stay with the embedded view anyway. Then your first column would be `status + @Subset($Updatedby;1)` and your "Show single category" formula `@If(@IsMember("[roleA]"; @UserRoles); "1"; @IsMember("[roleB]"; @UserRoles); "2"; "3") + @UserName`.

Comment: One more question, how would I add another check into the formula above? e.g. if archive = 0? adding it with a "+" sign doesnt seem to yield desired results

Comment: You'd put that in view's "View Selection" formula as I assume you want to show documents with archive=0 only: `SELECT Form="formA" & archive=0`. Only conditions which are **different** between users you have to put into first categorized column and "Show single category" formula

Answer (score 3):

Using "dynamic" selection statements most often is a bad idea. Therefor it doesn't matter, if you use a SPOFU- View (Shared, Private on first use) or single category.

Each of the solutions has different disadvantages. 
If the number of roles is finite and does not change that often, I would suggest to create one view for each role with the right selection formula.

Then you use an Outline, and in this outline you simply compute the title and which view to show for each user with the appropriate formula.

That way, the user can do anything in the view: Search, sort, filter, etc. and does not have any restrictions...

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggest in first place - see my second paragraph :)

Comment: Similar experience = similar answer :)