# @Username when run on server

Tags: lotus-notes

So we recently decided to change some private views in a database to normal views. However, there is @Username in the select formula and when not calculated in a private view it obviously displays the server name.

Is there any way or function to get the username of the actual user and not the server?

Greetings,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The view gets calculated on server and @UserName won't work there. The [documentation of @UserName](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_USERNAME.html) points out:

> You should not use
>   @UserName in a public view, doing so produces unpredictable results.

As a workaround you can add a first categorized column with user names calculated or contained by document fields and embed this view in a form or page. There you can use @UserName to show only the category of current user ([have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710155/2065611)).

Comment: I started my answer before Knut's appeared. We're saying bascially the same thing.

Comment: The way I understood it, the value in the first categorized column needs to be the same as the value in the "Show single category" property of the embedded view. However, I have a list of usernames in my categorized column and I don't think it's possible to add an @IsMember-function in the "Show single category" property.

Comment: If the first categorized column shows the user names, then the "show single category" formula would be `@UserName` or `@Name([CN]; @UserName)` depending on how the names look like in categorized column (full qualified names with organisation or just common name).

Comment: What I mean is I have more usernames per document. So there's more usernames per row. And I need to check if @UserName is a member of those usernames.

Comment: If your column is categorized then user names should be listed *separately*.  The user related documents should be listed below every single user name.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want a view to dispay data specific to a user, that's what private views are for.

Even if you set up a shared view to discard its index and rebuild every time, shared views are still going to be built by the Indexer running on the server, running under the server's indentity. And it would be terribly inefficient to recalculate views for each user on the fly anyhow.

One alternative is to use views categorized by name, and design your applications to use embedded views with the Show Single Category option enabled.If the scale of the application is not too terribly large, this can work well - but it will be faster for users whose names come earlier in thew view's sort order than the users whose names come toward the end, so keep that in mind when evaluating performance.